# how to accept only registered users through a login page

Tags: php, stored-procedures

I am looking to create a login page through which only registered users can login. i have tried following code but it's not working. I have mentioned my stored procedure as well as my login page code.

```
create procedure cp(in username,in password,out yes_no)
  BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO yes_no
    FROM user1 u
    WHERE u.USERNAME = username && u.PWD = password_p;         
  END

<body>

<h2>Login Form</h2>

<form action="/action_page.php">


  <div class="container">
    <label><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
 $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "seb");
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, 
 "CALL cp") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I want to add validation for a login page using a stored procedure**

Nikhil try to understand the basic concept first. `Stored Procedure` are not meant for validating data, its server side script which can deal with this. Make your server side script like it can get the user entered value, validate it with different rules, if valid, call the stored procedure with these values.